# Is there a Utility to search chain of call programs in a selected program?

Tags: shell-script

I have mf cobol program in unix. I need to find out how many called programs are called from it and then called programs within called programs and so on?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all the programs launched by a command you can use `strace` with the `-f` option to follow children too.

For example, collecting all the output of a `bash -c` command into file `/tmp/out`:

```
$ strace -f -o /tmp/out -e execve bash -c 'ls -d . | cat -n; date' 
$ grep 'execve(' /tmp/out
```

will show the commands and their parameters:

```
758   execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "ls -d . | cat -n; date"], ) = 0
759   execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls", "-d", "."],  <unfinished ...>
760   execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat", "-n"],  <unfinished ...>
761   execve("/usr/bin/date", ["date"], ) = 0
```

Alternatively, assuming your kernel was configured with CONFIG_FTRACE, you can use [execsnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/execsnoop)
, one of the scripts from the Brendan Gregg trace and performance collection, to show all commands being run on the system.  Example output when running the same 2 commands above:

```
$ sudo /opt/perf-tools-master/bin/execsnoop
Tracing exec()s. Ctrl-C to end.
Instrumenting sys_execve
   PID   PPID ARGS
  1567   2134 strace -f -o /tmp/out -e execve bash -c ls -d . | cat -n; date [...]
  1569   1567 bash -c ls -d . | cat -n; date
  1570   1569 ls -d .
  1571   1569 cat -n
  1572   1569 date
  1575   2134 grep execve( /tmp/out
^C
Ending tracing...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you can use

```
pstree <name_of_your_cobol_program_process>
```

which will show a tree of all the subprocesses called by your program.